# C++ code translation and name lookup

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, analysis

**My question is**: At what phase does the compiler perform name `lookup`. I think it may be when it perform semantic analysis, but I just want to make sure, since when I was searching about compiler analysis, they didn't mention name lookup in any of this phases (lexical,syntax,semantic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, name lookup generally needs to be done as part of syntax analysis (parsing), as when names are type names or template names, that affects the syntax.  To the extent that things can be parsed indpendently of typenames or template names, name lookup may be deferred until later, but that's generally an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

It's semantic analysis in general, but in C++, the stages are all intertwined, so it's understandable if someone says something else.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, sometimes you can't decide the semantic meaning of a syntactic element, without knowing it's kind (type, variable, etc.). Most C++ compilers use generated grammar (yacc, bison) for building the syntax tree, so the name lookup must come after that.

consider the following:

A * B;

this is either the declaration of the variable B of type A *, or a statement calling operator * on it arguments A and B.